# App won't install after updating google play services (8.1 to 8.3)

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

In my build.gradle I have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

and everything works like a charm.

When I change services' version to the latest 8.3.0, I get something like this:

```
Installing com.example.app
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.app"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.app
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.app
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

My SDK is up to date, Android Studio alerts me of the newer version and my device's services version is 8.3.01

Am I missing something? I didn't find anything in the changelog and I'm stuck with this for hours...

**EDIT - solution is simpler than you may think**

I wasn't expecting this as I didn't even have my older app version installed, but some data was still there. I just needed to install old, working version once again, clear the data, uninstall, and the problem is gone. All credits to **Alex K** and his answer.

Comment: This happened to me too after updating Google Play Services from 8.1 to 8.3. I found out that the library is adding a provider in the application manifest that is causing this error. For now I had to downgrade to version 8.1 until I find a solution.

Comment: @MiguelBotón solved.

Comment: The issue ( and a workaround ) is described here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, Android is having a tough time uninstalling the old version of the app while trying to sideload the new version.

To fix this, you can manually uninstall the old version of the app. Go to Settings, then Applications, then tap on your app, clear the data, then Uninstall. After that, try installing the new verison of your app again, and everything should work just fine.

This happens sometimes when you have conflicting versions of apps.

Comment: Sadly, after hours of trying other solutions, this helped. To tell the truth, I didn't even consider your answer as I was uninstalling the app manually before. But it's clearing the data that does the magic. I needed to install app with 8.1 once again, clear, uninstall and suddenly, it works. Years of developing apps and android is still surprising me in such an unpleasant manner...

Answer (score 1):

This is for your reference only.

1. In the debug environment, a Provider with the same name possibly is exsited. Try to edit the `android:authorities="xxx"` in the AndroidManifest.xml to some other value.
2. When you repeat to install a android apk, this failure would possibly be shown. Try to open the menu of your emulator:
   settings->applications->mange
   applications-> select the application->select "unistall".
   and then install your apk again.

I'm not sure, just have a try?